# dplyr passing column names as a variable with is.na filter

Tags: r, dplyr, na

I am aware that similar questions have been asked and I have tried multiple options but I am still having an error message.

```
df_construction <- function(selected_month, selected_variable){
  selected_variable_en <- rlang::enquo(selected_variable) #This was an attempt following the link

  #filter_criteria <- interp(!is.na(~y), .values = list(y = as.name(selected_variable))) This doesn't work

  df1 <- airquality %>%
    dplyr::filter(Month == selected_month,
                  !is.na(selected_variable_en))%>%
    select(Month, Day, !!selected_variable)

  return(df1)}


df1 <- df_construction(2, "Solar.R")
```

My ultimate goal is to build this in Shiny and thus have inputs the user will have selected as arguments in the function.

I know that the `filter` and the `select` functions shouldn't be dealt with in the same way.

I have followed the steps according to: https://www.brodrigues.co/blog/2016-07-18-data-frame-columns-as-arguments-to-dplyr-functions/ but had no success due to the `!is.na` filter.

I just want to have a dataframe where the only columns are the `Month` column for the selected months, the `Day` column and whichever column from the choice `Ozone, Solar.R, Wind, Temp` the user has selected, without any NA.

Thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!!` is often not enough to unquote variable names. You often need them in conjunction with `rlang::sym`. And if you have more than one variable to unquote, you need to use `!!!` and `rlang::syms`

```r
df_construction <- function(selected_month, selected_variable){

df1 <- airquality %>%
    dplyr::filter(Month == selected_month,
                  !is.na(!!rlang::sym(selected_variable_en)))%>%
    select(Month, Day, selected_variable)

return(df1)
}
```

For `select`, you can directly put variable names. There has been a new functionality in `dplyr` to unquote `{{}}` but it does not work in all cases.

If you start writing variables names in functions, you might have difficulties with `dplyr`. In that aspect, `data.table` is easier to use (see [a blog post I wrote on the subject](https://linogaliana.netlify.app/post/datatable/datatable-nse/))